# Excel Chart. How do I convert datatype of legend and format it

Tags: excel, charts

I have a chart. X-axis is full date. I wish to make

1. X-Axis the month
2. Legend should be the year

In other words, one month should have several bars for each year.

I tried right clicking, selecting format Legend. I am really stumped.

Here is screenshot of what I have

[image]

Comment: It's not really a programming question is it? See [help/on-topic]. Suggest deleting this and posting here: [Super user](https://superuser.com).

Comment: I tried posting there, but in vain @Spinner

Comment: Well, that's the place for this sort of question. So either, what you're doing isn't possible or you haven't explained it well enough. I'll be honest here and say the above is confusing. You talk about wanting to change the Legend, and yet your posted image has you editing the Axis (not the Legend). Suspect if you get that right, the answer with be forthcoming soon enough.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to make a pivot chart, then insert a graph.